# How do I reuse golang http request in python request

Tags: python-3.x, go, python-requests

So I have a tls proxy that I am running in golang and I am sending the requests through python requests into the proxy. But I don't get the headers and cookies back in python requests. How can I reuse the headers and cookies that I get when using the tls proxy from golang into my python request? I can see that the new headers and cookies are being created in the golang tls proxy, but how can I transfer the new headers and cookies into python requests?

Golang code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/url"
    "strings"

    http "github.com/useflyent/fhttp"

    "github.com/Carcraftz/CycleTLS/cycletls"
)

var client = cycletls.Init()

func main() {
    port := flag.String("port", "8082", "A port number (default 8082)")
    flag.Parse()
    addr := "127.0.0.1:" + string(*port)
    fmt.Println("Hosting a TLS API on http://" + addr)
    http.HandleFunc("/", handleReq)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(addr, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Error starting the HTTP server:", err)
    }

}

func handleReq(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    defer r.Body.Close()
    // Ensure page URL header is provided
    pageURL := r.Header.Get("Poptls-Url")
    if pageURL == "" {
        http.Error(w, "ERROR: No Page URL Provided", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    // Remove header to ignore later
    r.Header.Del("Poptls-Url")

    // Ensure user agent header is provided
    userAgent := r.Header.Get("User-Agent")
    if userAgent == "" {
        http.Error(w, "ERROR: No User Agent Provided", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    // Extract proxy from header
    proxy := r.Header.Get("Poptls-Proxy")
    if proxy != "" {
        r.Header.Del("Poptls-Proxy")
    }

    redirectVal := r.Header.Get("Poptls-Allowredirect")
    allowRedirect := true
    if redirectVal != "" {
        if redirectVal == "false" {
            fmt.Println(("redirects disabled"))
            allowRedirect = false
        }
    }
    if redirectVal != "" {
        r.Header.Del("Poptls-Allowredirect")
    }
    // Change JA3
    // Use Chrome JA3 by default
    //TODO: ADD MORE JA3 HASHES
    tlsClient := "771,4865-4866-4867-49195-49199-49196-49200-52393-52392-49171-49172-156-157-47-53,0-23-65281-10-11-35-16-5-13-18-51-45-43-27-21,29-23-24,0"
    if strings.Contains(strings.ToLower(userAgent), "firefox") {
        tlsClient = "771,4865-4867-4866-49195-49199-52393-52392-49196-49200-49162-49161-49171-49172-156-157-47-53-10,0-23-65281-10-11-35-16-5-51-43-13-45-28-21,29-23-24-25-256-257,0"
    }

    // Forward body
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)

    // Forward query params
    var addedQuery string
    for k, v := range r.URL.Query() {
        addedQuery += "&" + k + "=" + v[0]
    }

    endpoint := pageURL + "?" + addedQuery
    if strings.Contains(pageURL, "?") {
        endpoint = pageURL + addedQuery
    } else if addedQuery != "" {
        endpoint = pageURL + "?" + addedQuery[1:]
    }
    u, err := url.Parse(endpoint)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // Forward headers
    headers := make(map[string]string)
    //fmt.Println(r.Cookies()) //Delete this
    //fmt.Println(r.Method)    //Delete this
    for k := range r.Header {
        if k != "Content-Length" {
            headers[k] = r.Header.Get(k)
        }
    }
    headers["Host"] = u.Host
    // Set options
    opts := cycletls.Options{
        Body:          string(body), // ideally, body should be passed as bytes
        Ja3:           tlsClient,
        UserAgent:     userAgent,
        Headers:       headers,
        Method:        r.Method,
        Proxy:         proxy,
        AllowRedirect: allowRedirect,
    }
    // Perform request
    res, err := client.Do(endpoint, opts, r.Method)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Request failed:", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(res.Response.Status)
    //fmt.Println(res.Response.Headers) //Delete this
    // Forward response headers
    for k, v := range res.Response.Headers {
        // Do not forward the content length and encoding headers, as we will handle the decoding ourselves
        if k != "Content-Length" && k != "Content-Encoding" {
            w.Header().Set(k, v)
        }

    }
    // Forward respone status
    w.WriteHeader(res.Response.Status)

    // Write forwarded proxy request
    if _, err := fmt.Fprint(w, res.Response.Body); err != nil {
        log.Println("Error writing body:", err)
    }

}
```

Python code:

```py
import cloudscraper
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from sys import argv



def main():
    req = cloudscraper.create_scraper()

    akamai_api_login = req.post(
        api,
        data={
            'usrnm':    'user',
            'pass':     'pass'
        }
    )

    abc = req.get(website_endpoint)
    print(f'cookie: {abc.cookies}')

    a_api = req.post(
        api_site,
        data={
            'hello': 'world'
        }
    )
    senreq = req.get(web)
    sendata = senreq.json()



    # Checking for valid
    # Using the TLS Proxy
    tls = req.post(
        'http://127.0.0.1:8082',
        headers={
            'poptls-url': website,
            'accept': '*/*',
            'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
            'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="88", "Google Chrome";v="88", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
            'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
            'sec-fetch-dest': 'script',
            'sec-fetch-mode': 'no-cors',
            'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.192 Safari/537.36'
        },
        json={
            'data': data
        },
        cookies= dict(abc.cookies)
    )

    print(tls.cookies)
    req.close()

main()
```